# How to Redirect every link beginning with the same word in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a lot of urls beginning with the same word to a new link.

Exemple:

- Redirect 301 /old-text-1/ /new-link/
- Redirect 301 /old-text-2/ /new-link/
- Redirect 301 /old-text-3/ /new-link/
- Redirect 301 /old-text-4/ /new-link/
- Redirect 301 /old-text-5/ /new-link/
- ...

Can I redirect all this links in a better way?

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/old-text(.*)$ /new-link/ [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the trailing slash when using `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess` context.

```
RewriteRule ^old-text(.*)$ /new-link/ [R=301,L]
```